# Use FTP rather than HTTP for file transfer in Django

Tags: django, ftp, filefield, django-file-upload

Is there any way to transfer huge files in Django using FileField..because eveytime i do using simple upload handler the Connection Timeout error occurs because of huge traffic generated.
I was thinking of using FTP for the same but do not know how to implement the same. Any suggestions???

The Upload handler method looks like :

```
    def handle_uploaded_file(file_abs_path,f):
         destination = open(file_abs_path, 'wb+')
         for chunk in f.chunks():
              destination.write(chunk)
         destination.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) includes an FTP and SFTP storage backend. Definitely worth a look, but look for any relevant open issues, too.

Comment: The documentation is not that clear, and its like not so often this approach is used.